# No MTP with BLU Studio C

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Unable to transfer files as notification status has no MTP when connected to my Dell PC. I have changed USB cables and ports. Also the device is not listed in my device manager nor is any ABD listed in device manager.  I have also done a hard reset on the android per BLU customer service without any change.

Comment: Just on your Dell PC, or have you tried it on other computers as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should install USB drivers for BLU devices that will make your computer recognise the phone.

Download [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-blu-usb-drivers)